# how to un-register one jquery event from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

i have a global object

```
e.g
   var globalVar ={};
   function handlerGlobalVar (input) {/* do something */}
```

in multiple place i will try to listen an event from this globalVar

```
e.g
     $(globalVar).on("my-event", handlerGlobalVar);
```

To keep my code clean, and avoid registering too many event, i want to un-register the event when i finished using. so will try to do

```
$(globalVar).off("my-event", handlerGlobalVar );
```

however, when i perform "off" from one place, it will off all the "my-event" handler, none of them would work if one of them perform "off"

any suggestion how to fix my issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What globalVar will store? An array of selectors? Where in your code do you perform you off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [namespaced event handler registration](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names), so try

```
$(globalVar).on("my-event.mynamepsace1", handlerGlobalVar);
$(globalVar).on("my-event.mynamepsace2", handlerGlobalVar);
```

then

```
$(globalVar).off("my-event.mynamepsace1", handlerGlobalVar);
```

now this will remove only the first registration because of the namespace used

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q4W2N/), [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q4W2N/1/)

---

But if you want to fire an handler only once then use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q4W2N/3/)

Answer (score 0):

[`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) has room for one more argument. The selector

```
var _selector = <my_class_or_id_element>
$(globalVar).off("my-event", _selector, handlerGlobalVar );
```

Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a64KP/8/)

```
 $('#my-id').on('my-event', function() {
     alert("nonce");
     $('#my-id').off('my-event');
  });
```